# How to add header to a dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataset, statistics

I need to read the ''wdbc.data' in the following data folder:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/

Doing this in R is easy using command read.csv but as the header is missing how can I add it? I have the information but don't know how to do this and I'd prefer do not edit the data file.

Comment: You can use argument col.names= in function read.csv() and provide your column names.

Comment: Remember to specify `header=FALSE` in your `read.csv` call

Comment: Just give the names of the header as names for the data frame.

Comment: I have the data-set splits with header available if you need it please let me know. I will put it on a web page or ftp for easy download.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do the following:

Load the data:

```
test <- read.csv(
          "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data",
          header=FALSE)
```

Note that the default value of the `header` argument for `read.csv` is `TRUE` so in order to get all lines you need to set it to `FALSE`.

Add names to the different columns in the data.frame

```
names(test) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")
```

or alternative and faster as I understand (not reloading the entire dataset):

```
colnames(test) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")
```

Comment: Without `header = FALSE` in `read.csv`, I think the OP will inadvertently drop a row of data.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `colnames` instead of names if you have `data.frame` or `matrix`

Comment: And a `data.table` in case anyone was wondering...6.5 years later

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem by creating an array of values and assigning that array:

```
newheaders <- c("a", "b", "c", ... "x")
colnames(data) <- newheaders
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you are interested in reading some data from a `.txt` file and only extract few columns of that file into a new `.txt` file with a *customized header*, the following code might be useful:

```
# input some data from 2 different .txt files:
civit_gps <- read.csv(file="/path2/gpsFile.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
civit_cam <- read.csv(file="/path2/cameraFile.txt",head=TRUE,sep=",")

# assign the name for the output file:
seqName <- "seq1_data.txt"

#=========================================================
# Extract data from imported files
#=========================================================
# From Camera:
frame_idx <- civit_cam$X.frame
qx        <- civit_cam$q.x.rad.
qy        <- civit_cam$q.y.rad.
qz        <- civit_cam$q.z.rad.
qw        <- civit_cam$q.w

# From GPS:
gpsT      <- civit_gps$X.gpsTime.sec.
latitude  <- civit_gps$Latitude.deg.
longitude <- civit_gps$Longitude.deg.
altitude  <- civit_gps$H.Ell.m.
heading   <- civit_gps$Heading.deg.
pitch     <- civit_gps$pitch.deg.
roll      <- civit_gps$roll.deg.
gpsTime_corr <- civit_gps[frame_idx,1]

#=========================================================
# Export new data into the output txt file
#=========================================================
myData <- data.frame(c(gpsTime_corr),
                     c(frame_idx),
                     c(qx),
                     c(qy),
                     c(qz),
                     c(qw))
# Write :
cat("#GPSTime,frameIdx,qx,qy,qz,qw\n", file=seqName)
write.table(myData, file = seqName,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Of course, you should **modify this sample script** based on your own application.

Answer (score 0):

this should work out,

```
      kable(dt) %>%
      kable_styling("striped") %>%
      add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2))
#OR
kable(dt) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "bordered")) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2)) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 4" = 4, "Group 5" = 2)) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 6" = 6))
```

for more you can check the [link](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#grouped_columns__rows)